# 404 error on loading css and js from Unisharp/Laravel filemanager on a 7.0 installation

Tags: css, laravel, http-status-code-404, file-manager, unisharp-file-manager

I am trying to integrate unisharp's filemanager 2.1 in a greek laravel 7.0 installation and I'm running into this weird problem: Everything seems to work fine up to the point I am about to choose files for uploading to the remote server. The "Choose files" button simply does not respond neither in CKEeditor nor in TinyMCE mode not even in standalone mode. My routes seem fine and I've published all vendors. I can create directories and delete them, and If I manually place files in the files or images folder I can see them and choose them. I encounter the same problem with the demo page. However the demo project from the github (v.1.7.9 I think) works perfectly out of the box!

[image: ![images browser]

The only thing which doesn't work is the upload button.
I've noticed that the css and js fail to load when the modal loads and my guess is that this is where the problem lies.

[image: ![console 404 errors]

However I can't find a way to make this work. I even tried to change the link tags inside index.blade.php, inside the vendors folder to try to stop pointing at the resource folder, I've changed the paths, purged the cache, nothing works.
Any ideas? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: What I did is to move css, images and js to public folder, and call them with `/js/example.js`, `/css/example.css`

Comment: Thank Carlos. Sounded like a viable workaround. However new problems occur. If I import directly the css and js then routes stop to function and variables inside script.js turn up as undefined.

Comment: Update: I uninstalled and reinstalled the dependency. After many tries and continuing on the previous logic, I copied as suggested, all the missing imports into the public folder, then edited all published views from the vendor files to point at the new location with {{ url('/css/file.css') }}. In the end it worked for me as well. Still I think this a workaround, not a solution.

Comment: Yes, it's a workaround, that's because I write here in comments and not in answers. But I had not trouble with it, I had no time when I did this. Anyways, in Laravel documentation you have a good reading to find  a real solution.

Comment: Oh, I apologise my friend, I didn't mean to be disrespectful. I really appreciate your advice, it saved my project! Thank you again for your time :)

Comment: It's all good, no problem!